# How to insert HTML using Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I require my chrome extension to insert html into a page. I am able to insert the html, but am having issues styling the inserted element the way I want.

[image]

The image above is an example of what I'm looking for. I looked at the CSS for the grey box that was inserted and tried to implement those same things, but I get an error in the console when I try to do that.

The error I get:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
```

The code I'm using to style it (CSS through JS):

```
(function() {

    // just place a div at top right
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.style.position = 'fixed';
    div.style.background-color = '505F69';
    div.style.box-sizing = 'border-box';
    // div.font-size = '16px';
    div.style.top = 0;
    div.style.right = 0;
    // div.textContent = 'test';
    div.style.zIndex = 1000000000;
    div.innerHTML += 'Injected!';
    document.body.appendChild(div);



})();
```

I get an error on line with "div.style.background-color" and "div.style.box-sizing".

Any advice on how to replicate this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "div.style.background-color" and "div.style.box-sizing".

use

"div.style.backgroundColor" and "div.style.boxSizing".

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't appear the way the image below looks. How do I create a grey box in the upper right corner of the page?

Comment: @sharataka     div.style.backgroundColor = '#505F69';

Comment: before the color number,there is a '#'